# median in R need numeric data

Tags: r, vector, statistics, median

I was trying to compute the median of a given vector, but when I tried I kept on getting an error:

```
median(returns)
Error in median.default(returns) : need numeric data

> returns
 [1] 0.001262733  -0.005048584 -0.009160197 0.010411955  -0.00542421 
 [6] -0.010982649 -0.005807832 0.000863131  -0.00210823  0.000117543 
[11] 0.001319904  0.005307534  0.005246006  0.008469327  0.006006664 
[16] -0.001411188 -0.011446652 0.002669714  0.003896259  -0.003060607
[21] 0.006306116  0.000895311  -0.006235211 -0.000856819 -0.00056599 
[26] 0.00808345   0.00038652   -0.004070623 0.008398158  -0.005976036
[31] 0.011270873  0.007959499  0.003776885  -0.000591663 0.001163452 
[36] 0.005759682  0.000678132  0.000609123  -0.000735042
40 Levels: -0.00056599 -0.000591663 -0.000735042 -0.000856819 ... 0.011270873

dput(returns)
structure(c(25L, 9L, 14L, 39L, 10L, 15L, 11L, 22L, 6L, 18L, 26L, 
31L, 30L, 38L, 33L, 5L, 16L, 27L, 29L, 7L, 34L, 23L, 13L, 4L, 
1L, 36L, 19L, 8L, 37L, 12L, 40L, 35L, 28L, 2L, 24L, 32L, 21L, 
20L, 3L), .Label = c("-0.00056599", "-0.000591663", "-0.000735042", 
"-0.000856819", "-0.001411188", "-0.00210823", "-0.003060607", 
"-0.004070623", "-0.005048584", "-0.00542421", "-0.005807832", 
"-0.005976036", "-0.006235211", "-0.009160197", "-0.010982649", 
"-0.011446652", "#DIV/0!", "0.000117543", "0.00038652", "0.000609123", 
"0.000678132", "0.000863131", "0.000895311", "0.001163452", "0.001262733", 
"0.001319904", "0.002669714", "0.003776885", "0.003896259", "0.005246006", 
"0.005307534", "0.005759682", "0.006006664", "0.006306116", "0.007959499", 
"0.00808345", "0.008398158", "0.008469327", "0.010411955", "0.011270873"
), class = "factor")
```

Comment: It looks like your data is being read in as a factor. Why are you calling it a factor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're reading it from excel, R is looking at the "DIV#0" messages and considering your data to be categorical, as if it was data saying "Blue", "Green", "Hazel", etc. So when you're asking for `median`, R is thinking you're asking for the median of eye color, which would make no sense.

To turn a list of factors into numbers:

```
returns.numbers <- as.numeric(as.vector(returns))
median(returns.numbers)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I don't understand why is there a "DIV#0" because when I typed "returns" I only saw numeric values (shown above in the problem as well)

Comment: One possibility is that excel could have stored the fact that at one point "DIV#0" (its error symbol basically) was in a cell, and passed it along as a factor level to R.

Comment: As a sidenote, be careful never to simply convert a `factor` to `numeric` by `as.numeric(returns)`, because R will turn the `levels` into numeric rather than the data in the correct order. It must first be turned into a `vector`, then `numeric`. Just saving you some of the frustration I've had to deal with...

Comment: Suppose I read a "DIV#0" into my variable returns using "returns <- sample$sampledata." Is there a way to remove that last element which is NA?

Comment: `returns <- na.omit(returns)`. "DIV#0" will be coerced into `NA` with the `as.numeric` function.

Comment: I just did that, however, I am getting the median(returns.number) to be 0. Now, I'm not sure if that is the right answer, because it is very unlikely for log(stock returns) to have a median of 0

Comment: On the numbers listed above, my R console told me the median is `0.000678132`. You can do `summary(returns)` to get good information about the dataset, and also check `options()$digits` to make sure R isn't rounding to too few digits.

Comment: Oh, I actually changed the input from 39 to like 7000 points. And my digits are out till 7. When I ran mean(returns.number) I get a nonzero answer, but when I do median, I get 0. Could it be that it is actually 0?

Comment: You can find the median manually. Do `Returns <- sort(Returns)`, this will put the whole thing in increasing order. Then do `Returns[length(Returns)/2]` - this will pick out the middle number. Note that if there's an even number of data points, there is no middle number - I'm not sure what R does in this case - either picks one of them or averages the two middle numbers.

Comment: Yep, it works fine. I get 0 as the answer. Thanks a bunch for all the help!!